# Android - Force View to appear in front of Toolbar?

Tags: android, user-interface, toolbar

By default, eg. having Toolbar and some other Views in FrameLayout container causes Toolbar to appear on top of other views, no matter what their (views) order is.

Is it possible to force some of the views (eg. floating action buttons) to appear in front of Toolbar or should look for workaround?

**edit:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <!-- some RecyclerView goes here also -->

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_content_add"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accentColor"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accentColor"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Problem: The oval button appears in front of RecyclerView, but behind Toolbar.

Comment: Share some code you have tried

Comment: The FloatingActionButton is basicaly FrameLayout

Comment: Can you just use immersive mode? https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: I need FAB to partialy overlap the Toolbar, immersive mode won't help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The floating action button has to have equal or higher `elevation` as the toolbar. Assuming your toolbar has elevation set to `8dp`, the FAB needs to have the same at least.

Basically widgets with higher elevation move physically above and stop respecting the XML order.

Comment: Thanks, thats right. Also the FAB class in the library I used had overriden (in order not to use it) setElevation method and that caused another problem, ehhm ;P

Comment: So you switched to another library? Or maybe `translationZ` would've worked.

Comment: I started to modify the lib, but yes `translationZ` is working, probably will end using it. Thanks :)

Comment: If you're supporting pre-Lollipop devices, you would need to check there as well, because FrameLayout is a bit different from RelativeLayout in terms of stacking views on the Z-axis

Comment: bravooooo Eugen